# Is it possible to lift a bald person with an airstream? (Coanda effect and Bernoulli's principle)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation, lift

Lately, a high school teacher called Bruce Yeany has been uploading some fluid dynamics demonstrations on his YouTube channel. Here's his [first demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuX8_2h4jJg) using various objects like vegetables and containers. He's also uploaded a follow-up [demo with dolls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOXRfj9hqhI&t=188s).

There's a comment thread at the time of writing on that second video about whether or not it would be possible to lift an actual bald person using a rapid airstream.

I wasn't sure how to start, so here are my assumptions:

- the person has average body proportions
- the head of a bald person is roughly three quarters of a sphere (at the back)
- the radius of that sphere is $r_{head}$ of about $8$ cm
- the mass of the person is $m_{person}$ of about $80$ kg
- atmospheric pressure of $1013$ hPa
- airstream velocity $v_{air}$ (variable)

From the [Bernoulli's principle wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle), I'm guessing that this scenario falls under the *compressible flow* category, but there seem to be three different formulae to get to an answer. Moreover, I'm not sure how to calculate the pressure required to actually lift a human.

Is there a way to model this scenario to get to some kind of answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer and I'd welcome comments, but here's where I've got to so far.

We need to generate a lift force of at least 80$g$ to lift our person, or about 800 N.

The area available to us for a pressure differential to act on is approximately $3\pi R^2$, 3/4 of the surface area of a sphere. That's about 0.06m$^2$. Therefore, we need a pressure differential of $800/0.06=13,300\,\mathrm{Pa}$.

The pressure differential in the normal direction due to streamline curvature is

$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial n} = -\frac{\rho V^2}{R},
$$

and this is where I'm a bit unsure. Far above the person's head, the velocity will be at atmospheric pressure. I think we can approximate the pressure differential as $\Delta P/L$, where $L$ is the normal distance which the pressure gradient is acting over. However, I don't know what we should take $L$ to be. If I arbitrarily take $L=1$ m, then with $\rho=1.2$ kg/m$^3$, we get $V\approx30$ m/s, or about 70 mph, which just feels too slow. Taking $L\approx R$ we get $V\approx100$ m/s, or about 30% of the speed of sound.

My gut says that levitating a bald man with an air jet shouldn't be possible, at the very least I think it wouldn't be practical.

Comment: Lovely answer! I was initially considering the surface area of a human as seen from below, but your pressure differential approach makes much more sense. Awesome stuff!